# How can I retrieve the wikipageID if the page is not in english using sparql and dbpedia

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I want to retrieve the wikipageID for the **same** query name in different languages. For example:

```
select * where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mike_Quigley_(footballer)> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID }
====>Mike_Quigley_(footballer)   17237449   en
select * where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Theodore_Roberts> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID }
====>Theodore_Roberts   6831454   en
select * where { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Theodore_Roberts> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID }
====>Theodore_Roberts      de
select * where { <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Theodore_Roberts> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID }
====>Theodore_Roberts      fr
select * where { <http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Theodore_Roberts> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID }
====>Theodore_Roberts      it
select * where { <http://ja.dbpedia.org/resource/セオドア・ロバーツ> dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?wikiID }
====>セオドア・ロバーツ      ja
```

---

In the first query `Mike_Quigley_(footballer)`which is in english I was able to retrieve its `ID  = 17237449`but when the language changes as you can see I cannot retrieve the wikipageIDs.

---

- How can I retrieve the ids of these pages
- The more complex part is that the following link [German language Theodore_Roberts](http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Theodore_Roberts) will lead me to a page where the property wikipageID is not **dbpedia-owl** It gets really complicated.
  Do you have any idea on how to solve it?

---

Amazing, when I try this query

```
SELECT ?uri ?id 
     WHERE {
         ?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id.
         FILTER (?uri = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lyon>) 
     }
```

I get the following result:

> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lyon  863863

---

But When I change the uri to `<it.dbpedia.org/resource/Lyon>` I get nothing.

Comment: Are you sure if you replace the uri with <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lyon>, it doesn't work? I just did and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Of course it will. But the question @Artemis What If i want Lyon from dbpedia Italy. What if i want the italian translation or the italian wikiPageId. Or any other language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to get the Italian version of your URI. But the problem is you are looking for the wrong URI. The Italian version of Lyon URI in English DBpedia is `http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Lione` and I am assuming you are using that. I found this out by:

```
SELECT * 
 WHERE {
     ?uri owl:sameAs ?b.
     FILTER (?uri = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lyon>) 
 }
```

And I couldn't get the Italian pageID from the English DBPedia.
When I tried in on the [Italian DBpedia](http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql), it worked :

```
SELECT ?uri ?id 
 WHERE {
     ?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID> ?id.
     FILTER (?uri = <http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Lyon>) 
 }
```

However, if you look at the Italian page `http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Lyon`, you can see that it has a property `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects` which is equal to `http://it.dbpedia.org/resource/Lione` that the owl:sameAs gives you. Maybe you can work your way through that.

Comment: @Armetis sorry if my question isn't clear. I only want to extract the Page ID that's all. As you can see in the example I can't extract the page ids when the language isn't english.

Comment: @HaniGoc since you are writing a python script and the pageID in both languages are different, I think the best way is to extract the owl:sameAs property from the English one and then feed it into the second ontology (the Italian one) with the dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects property and then get the id. Hope this helps.